# RDLC report: more than one page? Custom page breaks?

Tags: reporting-services, rdlc, report, page-break

I have a Microsoft Reporting Services report (local report, VS2005) and am trying to produce a rather tricky report...

I have two tables returned from a SQL query. The first is a master table that has a list of set ID's corresponding to sets of records in the second, and has a record set like so:

```
+----------------------+
| SetID                |
+----------------------+
| 1                    |
| 2                    |
| 3                    |
| ...                  |
|                      |
```

The second table is a list of bjorks, let's call them. It looks like this:

```
+----------+-------+-----------+-----------
| BjorkID  | SetID | BjorkName | ...
+----------+-------+-----------+-----------
| 1        | 1     | Bob       |
| 2        | 1     | Jones     |
| 3        | 1     | Smith     |
| 4        | 2     | Jack      |
| 5        | 2     | Daniels   |
| 6        | 3     | Moo       |
| 7        | 3     | Bean      |
| 8        | 3     | Bond      |
| 9        | 3     | Jim       |
| ...      | ...   | ...       |
|          |       |           |
```

Now, I need to generate a report that prints off one page for each Set, and each Set's page contains a list of its Bjorks.

Can anyone point me in the right direction to mangle RDLC into doing this? :)

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish your task with just the second table/data set and parent and detail groups on a table or list.

Parent groups on SetID. Detail groups on BjorkID. Set your page breaks accordingly.

HTH

Comment: Ahh excellent! I came to this conclusion myself yesterday, but only in rough form. Many thanks for confirming! :) F